# Algolia model integration within Django - possible ways to handle various field types

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views, algolia

I have a model with various different field types that I want the Algolia search engine to index correctly. So far I have been able to handle `models.char_fields` pretty straightforwardly - I'm now thinking, what's the best way to index various other field types (e.g., `ForeignKey` "objects", `ImageFields`, `DateTime` fields etc etc).

One thing I have noticed is that Algolia will fetch and store a `DateTimeField` as Unix standard time...so, originally I thought I could render something human readable on the template using `{% humanize %}`, but to no luck.

I was wondering if anyone knew of ways of dragging out useful information from the model - one idea I have had is to grab the object within the view and then bring out a unique identify for each returned object, then work some conditional flow to marry up that unique ident to the model, then I can work with that model as normal...? Such as:

```
def instant_search(request):
    posts = Post.published.all()

    context = {
        'appID': settings.ALGOLIA['APPLICATION_ID'],
        'searchKey': settings.ALGOLIA['SEARCH_API_KEY'],
        'indexName': get_adapter(Post).index_name,
        'posts': posts,
    }

    return render(request, 'blog/frame/instant_search.html', context)
```

The within the template I can use `{% for posts in post %} {% if post.id = _highlightResult.id.value %} ...do some stuff {% endif %} {% endfor %}`

If this isn't quite fast enough (and I'm pretty much guaranteeing it won't) I was wondering if Algolia can handle key information, such as dragging out the url for an image which is defined in the model as an `ImageField` e.g., much like I would with e.g., `post.image.url` in the template or a human readable value taken from a `DateTime` field  `models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)` in the model. It would be really nice to do this as Algolia indexes the defined model fields...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figured this one out:

In `models.py` I had to define attribute methods to obtain a manipulated bespoke value for Algolia to understand:

e.g., I have defined the following in the class for the model I wish to index:

```
def image_url(self):
    """Get upload_to path specific to this photo: Algolia recognizable format."""
    return self.image_scroll_1.url

def published_date(self):
    """Returns a humanized date format for Algolia indexing."""
    humanized_published_date = str(self.publish.strftime("%A, %d, %B %Y %I:%M%p"))
    return humanized_published_date
```

Hopefully this will help anyone else who is working with Algolia and working off various tutorials (I'm using Django by Example).

These can then be referenced in index.py as follows:

from algoliasearch_django import AlgoliaIndex

```
class PostIndex(AlgoliaIndex):
    fields = ('title', 'post_author', 'lead_in', 'published_date', 'keyword_tags', 'image_url', 'get_absolute_url')
```

Along with any other optional parameters you may like.